# Sending an instance of one VM to another VM in MVVM C#

Tags: c#, object, mvvm, instance, ooad

I'm complicating my own life here.
I'm trying to send an instance of one VM to another VM.

I have successfully sent objects to new VM before, such as Lists or variables. But I am getting confused with sending an instance of the VM.

For example, I have AViewModel.cs

I want to do my work in the VM, so some methods are done. Then at the end, I want to send this VM to BViewModel.cs

I would usaully go: `BViewModel bview = new BViewModel(aview)`

Can someone please tell me where I would define the instance of A?

If there are any other questions or a need for more info, please comment and I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.nl/2009/05/mvvm-communication-among-viewmodels.html) tutorial explains different way of communication between ViewModels.